# List and detail controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

If I have 2 controllers; List and detail controller, what is the correct way to handle memory management for these 2 controllers?

I mean at what point should release be called on them?

Also in case my list controller is dynamic (i.e. data gets called from ext web service) and some data is passed to detail controller, where exactly should I write the code to retrieve/display the data in detail controller. I mean should it be viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear ?

Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single answer. But my answer is.... `viewWillAppear`

Take a detail view which is almost never used. So maybe you decide to create one each time it's used and destroy it after every use.

Take another detail view which may be used frequently. You decide create it once and just re-use it. Maybe you even destroy it on low-memory warnings and re-create it the next time it's used. In this case, you can't depend upon `viewDidLoad` being called each time the

Using `viewWillAppear` makes my code more consistent and makes it easier to make a change when I realize that detail view is being called a lot more than I expect. I should re-use it instead of creating it every time.

As to when you should release them... that really depends on what perspective. How often is it used? How much memory does it take to simply exist? How much work does it take to re-create?

Comment: In case of viewDidLoad (when the user navigates back & forth between LC & DC), is viewDidLoad called everytime or if there is some time gap ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best way to istantiate the detail view controller is:

```
MyDetailController * dc = [[MyDetailController alloc] initWithMyObject: anObject];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: dc animated: YES];
[dc release];
```

where anObject is the piece of your downloaded data you want to present in the detail view controller.

I assume your list controller is the main one of your app, which should be instantiate as follows:

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
_baseWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
_listVC = [MyListController new];
[_baseWindow addSubview: _listVC.view];
[_baseWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

And released:

```
- (void) dealloc {
[_listVC release]; _listVC = nil;
[_baseWindow release]; _baseWindow = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

Remember that -viewDidLoad is called after -loadView, which in turn is called when someone tries to access the -view property of the view controller.

Thus you may want to prepare your view in -viewDidLoad and do some additional tasks in -viewWillAppear or -viewDidAppear. Please note that -viewWillAppear (and similar methods) is called EVERY TIME that view controller's view is shown on screen. That is, for example, if you push another VC from detail vc and then pop, -viewDidAppear will be called again.